# orgmode capture template: adding sub headers

Tags: org-mode

i have the following template

```
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
               '("un" "resturant"
                 entry
                (file+headline "/home/zeltak/org/files/agenda/travel.org" "NYC")
"* TOVISIT %^{Description}   
%u
  :PROPERTIES:
  :Rating: %^{rating?|-|1|2|3|4|5}
  :price: %^{price in local currancy?|-|0-10|10-20|20-30|30-50|50+}
  :Source: %^{Source?}
  :Type: %^{Type?|meal|breakfeast|dessert|street}
  :Cuisine:   
%^{Cuisine?|-|Indian|Thai|Vietnamese|Asian|Chinese|Israeli|Italian|American|EastEuro|Mexican|French|Persian|Austrian|Japan}
  :Fav: %^{Fav|yes|no}
  :END:

%^{prompt|** My Review}
%?
    "
       ))
```

note the last entry where i try and add a sub header. when i finzalize the capture it dosent create a header but rather just add the 2 starts.

is there a way to make the capture template add a proper sub header?

Comment: This is quite an elaborated capture template. I tried and it works fine. At the prompt to ask for review title, you just type ** <title>. If it is a general fixed title, you can omit the prompt there.

Comment: hmm here it just add a ** (with a space before) the two ** and dosent create a sub header. i have to manually go and delete blank spaces before  the **..weird

Comment: A banal idea: maybe reload the template to make sure you got the correct one in place. And if that does not work, remove the prompt, just leave a straight sub header there and see if it works first.

Comment: thx. i reloaded without the prompt but with a *** entry. what this does when the template is executed is to have a *** text yet not an actual header. i need to manually go and change each subheader to a header by deleting the white space before the ***.

Comment: Three asterisks are correct: * NYC => ** TOVISIT ... => *** Sub-header (review title). I just don't understand why you would get that space before the asterisks. I suggest you to try with a minimum template with only the headers (without the PROPERTIES parts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer for you. Make sure you have no space(s) before this part in the *template definition*: `%^{prompt|** My Review}`. This is because `orgmode` will retain exact whitespace structure like you instructed in the template. Furthermore, avoid using multiple character in the shortcut key `"un" "restaurant"` should be something like `"u" "restaurant"`. Actually I could not use that two letters shortcut myself.

Comment: thx that worked for me :)

Comment: Great to know it worked :)